# Remove visibility for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I would like in my plugin to make a custom post type only in admin.
When I register my cpt, I do this :

```
$args = [
  'public' => false,
  'publicly_queryable' => false,
]; 
register_post_type( $post_type, $args );
```

It seems to be correct but when I edit it, I can still modify the visibility.

How can I remove the visibility for this custom post type ?

Comment: Perhaps you take a look at `post__not_in` and use [`$wp_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

Answer (score -1):

```
function force_type_private($post)
{
    if ($post['post_type'] == 'my_post_type')
    $post['post_status'] = 'private';
    return $post;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'force_type_private');
```

please try above code, I hope this will work for you.